# "uncaught exception: ReferenceError: require is not defined :" inside init-db.js docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using volumes to populate a MongoDB instance within Docker. In order to access and parse the data, I am using papaparse and request (it is depreciated but still works for my use case). When I use the require keyword at the top of the script to import the libraries, I get the following error: uncaught exception: ReferenceError: require is not defined :.

In my dockerfile, I have installed npm, nodejs, and copied the package.json. So, I don't know why it doesn't understand the "require" keyword. I've also tried using import, but that results in a similar error.

Here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install npm

RUN apt-get -y install nodejs

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt ./app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*

COPY package.json ./app

RUN npm install
```

Here is the init-db.js:

```js
const papa = require("papaparse");
const request = require("request");

const options = {/* options */};

const dataStream = request.get("https://example.com/myfile.csv");
const parseStream = papa.parse(papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, options);

dataStream.pipe(parseStream);

let data = [];
parseStream.on("data", chunk => {
    data.push(chunk);
});

parseStream.on("finish", () => {
// Doing something with the data.
    }
});
```

This is fairly new to me, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you check if your `package.json` contains `type:module` or not?

Comment: @AnirudhModi, I created the package.json using the "npm init" command, so there is no type:module.

Comment: the `init-db` file I am assuming that you are "not running in browser", and you are running this in node itself? Reason being, if this code is running in browser then `require` is not available in browser, and require is only available in node, or you may to use `browserify` https://browserify.org/ or `webpack`

Comment: @AnirudhModi, you are correct. I am running this in node itself.

Answer (score 0):

The folks over at [coderslang](https://learn.coderslang.com/0021-nodejs-require-is-not-defined-error/) suggest trying:

- change the type of modules in package.json to commonjs:

```
"type": "commonjs"
```

- delete the string "type": "module" from the file package.json
- change the require to import:

```
// const express = require('express');
import express from 'express';
```

Comment: I tried all of these but for some reason, it still isn't working. Is it because papaparse is not allowed to be used in init-db.js?

Comment: No, there error is telling you that the `require` function is not defined, so you won't be able to require anything.